# How to detect "EOF" in a network stream using XML protocol?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, networking

I want to design and implement a xml based network protocol. I have two network machines each running a java app. One (client C) sends a XML sheet to the other (server S). S processes some data and send another XML sheet back to C.

Now I'd like to use SAX as XML parser. To terminate the `parse()` routine of SAX it is nescessary, that the end of the stream is well defined. In a classical file reading scenario this is trivial.

At first I tried to terminate the socked to indicate the EOS but then no answer can be transmitted anymore.

In this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614351/how-to-specify-end-of-file-when-sending-it-over-network) a similar question is asked. There seems to exist multiple solutions:

- As soon as the root element of the request XML is read in, SAX is stopped (via `SAXException`). It looks bad to me to rely on an exception to terminate an algorithm... I think this is bad programming style, isn't it?
- I count the bytes to be transmitted to the server and send this number before the XML file. But then I need to create the XML beforehand to calculate the size. Also not best practice in my eyes.

So can you give me a hint how to establish this as easy and as elegant as possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to stop parsing when you reach the end of the document, you could just detect that `endElement()` has been called on the root element of the document. You'll need to be able to recognize the root element of course, but that should be easy enough to do just by keeping a counter with the current depth.

Admittedly this won't detect when there's extra information in the stream, but I wouldn't anticipate that being a problem in most cases.

Comment: The `endDocument()` is called on reaching the end of the stream. On a file this is typically EOF. On a network socket on the other hand there is no ent of stream except for closing the socket (as far as I know). As soon as I close the socket, I cannot transmit the Answer (S->C) anymore, as the socket is closed already.

Comment: @ChristianWolf: Are you *sure* about that? I'd expect `endDocument()` to be called when the closing tag of the document was reached. If it isn't though, I have another idea - will edit that in.

Comment: @ChristianWolf: Having re-read the documentation, I see that you're right, so I'll take the `endDocument` solution out, just leaving the `endElement` part.

Comment: So you think if the `endElement()` of the root element is reached, I should stop parsing. So far so good. How to stop the `parse()` method from within the `endElement()` method? Using `SAXException`?

Comment: @ChristianWolf: It's definitely not nice to do that, but it *may* be the best bet. Does `parse()` just hang if you don't, waiting for more input? (It's been a while since I've used SAX.) Do you have to use SAX itself - could you use StAX for example instead?

Comment: Yes, SAX `parse()` just stops and waits for more input. I have not used StAX yet, I have to work it  out. Is there a big difference? Is it included in standard java or as external depndency?

Comment: @ChristianWolf: It certainly *used* to be an extra dependency, but it may not be now. It's been a while since I've done much XML work in Java I'm afraid. (My answer is probably worth deleting at this point, to be honest. Let me know when you've read this comment and I'll kill it.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31135/discussion-between-christian-wolf-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score -1):

Use HTTP to implement the transport layer, it is a standard and in it's 1.1 version it supports the KeepAlive to do what you describe.

Comment: I do not need the KeepAlive. The problem is on the server side. As far as I have seen, there is not API for easy creation of a HTTP *server*, meaning waiting for connections. The other way around is quite straightforward.

Comment: Keepalive has nothing to do with end of stream.